# Lagrangian mechanics- conservation of energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, cylindrical-coordinates

Consider a single particle system whose Lagrangian remains the same if the position of the particle is simultaneously (i) rotated by an arbitrary angle s about the z-axis and (ii) shifted by an amount cs in the z-direction (where c is some constant). (The Lagrangian does not have to remain the same if the position is only shifted or only rotated.) Find a conserved quantity of this system. (It is helpful to use cylindrical coordinates.)

so I started by arriving at the following cylindrical coordinates (cscos(s),cssin(s),cs). After that I calculated the kinetic energy and potential energy to find the lagrangian=o.5ms^2c^2Ṡ^2 -mgcs 
Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: Is the Lagrangian here $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}{\bf \dot{r}}^2 - mg z$ (as you seem to assume) or are you to consider a general Lagrangian? The results you are to derive are special cases of what is known as Noethers theorem.

Comment: The one I assumed yes

Comment: The way you phrase the question makes it look like you want to consider a general Lagrangian (and that's the interesting problem and is a special case of Noethers theorem). For this specific Lagrangian it's not hard to simply derive the equation of motion and then solve them to find the constants of motion. Try to show that the angular momentum about the $z$ axis $L_z = \dot{x}y - \dot{y}x$ is conserved and the energy $E = \frac{1}{2}[\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 + \dot{z}^2] + mgz$ is conserved (show $\dot{L_z} = 0$ and $\dot{E} = 0$ using the equations of motion).

Comment: How would we do this if we were to consider a general Lagrangian?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest we can take a general Lagrangian $L$.

**Noether's Theorem** states that if a change of coordinates in the Lagrangian gives rise in a change of the Lagrangian only up to a total derivative then conserved quantities arise:
\begin{equation}L(q'_i,\dot q'_i,t)=L(q_i,\dot q_i,t)+\epsilon \frac{d}{dt}\alpha(q_i,t) ,\quad\delta q_i=\epsilon\xi^i(q,t)
\end{equation}
Then we have conserved quantities 
\begin{equation}
J=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i}\xi^i
\end{equation}

**Invariance of Translation in the Z-Direction**

Now if we transform our radius vector along the $z$ axis by an infinitesimal amount $\epsilon$ (which IS used as the same $\epsilon$ as above also) we get under this transformation:
\begin{equation}
z \mapsto z + \epsilon, \quad \delta z=\epsilon , \quad L \mapsto L + 0
\end{equation}
Thus: $\epsilon \frac{d}{dt}\alpha(q_i,t)=0$ (as per your question the Lagrangian stays the same).
Thus using Noether's Theorem we can now find the conserved charge:

Now multiplying both sides of J by $\epsilon$ we get:
\begin{equation}
J\epsilon=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot z}\epsilon\xi
\end{equation}

Now by Noether's Theorem $\epsilon\xi=\delta z = \epsilon$, so in fact:
\begin{equation}
J\epsilon=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot z}\epsilon \implies J=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot z}
\end{equation}
Is the conserved charge: which is exactly linear momentum in the z direction.

**For the Rotation about Z axis**
You would need to do a similar computation, except more difficult as we really need to worry about three dimensions. Let i range from 1 to 3, and let summation convention be assumed; with 
\begin{equation}
\delta x_i = \varepsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_jx_k, \quad \delta \vec{r} = \vec{\epsilon} \times \vec{r} 
\end{equation}
Where $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is the $3\times 3$ Levi-Civita tensor.

> Can you derive the conserved charge from here, using Noether's Theorem?